# Openshift: unable to validate against any security > context constraint

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I try to create the following statefulSet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
  namespace: efk
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.2.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        env:
        - name: cluster.name
          value: k8s-logs
        - name: node.name
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts
          value: "es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch"
        - name: discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes
          value: "2"
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: "-Xms256m -Xmx256m"
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "pv0002"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Mi
```

Unfortunately I run in the following exception which I don't seem to be able to resolve:

> create Pod es-cluster-0 in StatefulSet es-cluster failed error: pods
>   "es-cluster-0" is forbidden: unable to validate against any security
>   context constraint:
>   [spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.privileged: Invalid value:
>   true: Privileged containers are not allowed
>   spec.initContainers[1].securityContext.privileged: Invalid value:
>   true: Privileged containers are not allowed
>   spec.initContainers[2].securityContext.privileged: Invalid value:
>   true: Privileged containers are not allowed]

I added:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged developer
```

Not sure what else I'm supposed to check, I expect it to work.

Note: I use CRC on Mac OSX locally. 
https://github.com/code-ready/crc

Edit, I went overboard and added all possible users that came to mind:

```
oc describe scc 

Name:                                           privileged
Priority:                                       <none>
Access:                                         
  Users:                                        system:admin,system:serviceaccount:openshift-infra:build-controller,developer,deployer,default,builder,statefulset-controller
  Groups:                                       system:cluster-admins,system:nodes,system:masters
Settings:                                       
  Allow Privileged:                             true
  Allow Privilege Escalation:                   true
  Default Add Capabilities:                     <none>
  Required Drop Capabilities:                   <none>
  Allowed Capabilities:                         *
  Allowed Seccomp Profiles:                     *
  Allowed Volume Types:                         *
  Allowed Flexvolumes:                          <all>
  Allowed Unsafe Sysctls:                       *
  Forbidden Sysctls:                            <none>
  Allow Host Network:                           true
  Allow Host Ports:                             true
  Allow Host PID:                               true
  Allow Host IPC:                               true
  Read Only Root Filesystem:                    false
  Run As User Strategy: RunAsAny                
    UID:                                        <none>
    UID Range Min:                              <none>
    UID Range Max:                              <none>
  SELinux Context Strategy: RunAsAny            
    User:                                       <none>
    Role:                                       <none>
    Type:                                       <none>
    Level:                                      <none>
  FSGroup Strategy: RunAsAny                    
    Ranges:                                     <none>
  Supplemental Groups Strategy: RunAsAny        
    Ranges:                                     <none>
```

Same error wtf...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fixed this by using:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged -z default -n efk
```

Manual:

> -z, --serviceaccount=[]: service account in the current namespace to use as a user